# pdfplumber rotates all pages in pdf

Tags: python, pdfplumber

I am trying to read a PDF using `pdfplumber` and it usually works, but if there is one page where the text is rotated, it rotates all other pages as well.
This is the code I use:

```py
import pdfplumber

pdf_path = "some_pdf.pdf"

with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:
    for page in pdf.pages:
        print(page.rotation)
```

Which outputs:

```
270
270
```

The first 270 should be 0 and the second is correct.
Assuming that zero means that the text is readable without rotating.